# How can I make my code wait until I got processed image from the server to display in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I am working on some Image processing functionality where I am getting a processed image after applying the algorithm from the server which is taking some 10-15 minutes time to have responded back, so I need my remaining HTML code should wait until I got my image URL responded back from the server using Javascript.

I have tried using Async await function to do so, but no success.

Expected Results:- HTML code should wait until the server returns the processed image as an URL.

Comment: You appear to believe that Stackoverflow is a code writing service. Please edit your question to show us what you have tried with a [mcve] and maybe we can help

Comment: You should put your image into some queue and process it asynchronously on the server. Client can ask server every X seconds if the image is ready or not.

Comment: Theoretical questions are simply offtopic. If you don't provide any code, and there is no obvious code attached, it's simply hard to give an answer

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to manage this is:

- If you can use websockets, emit the response through it
- If you can't use websockets, make a request every (IE) 5s to the server to know what's the progress of the processing.

Long story short, you have to rely on the server to know the state of the image processing.

Since I don't know your server code I cannot be more specific.

Comment: Do you have any other simpler option along with sample code. I am really don't understand this?

Comment: I don't even know what's your backend, you have to hit your server every (IE) 10s to check if image is avaliable